# Doctrine ORM: map results from stored procedure into entities + divide results into groups

Tags: symfony, stored-procedures, doctrine-orm, mariadb

For Symfony 4.4 + Doctrine ORM 2.8 + Maria DB 10.5:

I need to retrieve data from MariaDB and map/hydrate it to multiple sets of entities. It must be done by single "CALL" of DB stored procedure (performance). In stored procedure, there is/are used SELECT(S) to return resultset(s).

Results must be "flagged" somehow to distinguish between different data sets later in Symfony 4 code.
For example "products from select 1", "products from select 2", ...

How to achieve that? I tried two approach, nothing works.

### Approach 1

I used multiple SELECT in stored procedure (each for single category). This returns multiple result sets, but I'm not able to iterate them in Doctrine ORM. I'm receiving just the first result set in Doctrine ORM.

### Approach 2

I used UNION for all SELECTs. Just one result set is returned, but I need to distinguish between individual rows (if Product is from SELECT 1, 2, ...). So I appended one extra column with flag "1", "2", ... This flag is only in DB, not in Product entity.

In Symfony all entities are mapped, but I don't have any access to extra "flag" to distinguish between them.

### Code

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder( $this->getEntityManager() );
$rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata( Product::class, 'p' );
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery("CALL MyProcedure(?)", $rsm);
$query->setParameter(1, $param, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$results = $query->getResult();
```

For approach 1: There is method "PDOStatement::nextRowset()", but is accessible just from DBAL, not ORM. I haven't find any way to map results from DBAL to ORM or iterate multiple result sets in ORM.

For approach 2: All entities are mapped, but I'm loosing access to my extra column with flag (not in entity and don't want extra field there). My idea is to loop entities + this extra column and separate this single result set inside Symfony using flag in extra column. Is it possible to access extra column somehow? I also tried some custom hydration method, but without success.

How to achieve my goal? I need working solution for at least one approach. Solution for both approaches is welcome.

### UPDATE

If it's possible to make it without adding "flag" field into entity, I would prefer it ("flag" is used just in this case and not anywhere else in app).
My idea: when hydrating is done, access some associative array also underline. Then iterate all entities and split by flag from this array.

### Some more code

In Product entity I have unique "ID" and some unimportant values (price, title, description, ....).

Approach 1 - stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Search (
    IN what VARCHAR(255)
    , IN offset INT
    , IN limits INT
)
BLOCK1: BEGIN

# ... some unimportant code

# BUILD standalone SELECTs (building SQL string)
SELECT GenerateSql(1,'c',0) INTO sqlSearchByCode;
SELECT GenerateSql(2,'b',0) INTO sqlSearchByBarcode;
SELECT GenerateSql(3,'n',0) INTO sqlSearchByName;

# PREPARE SQL
PREPARE stmtSearchByCode FROM sqlSearchByCode;
PREPARE stmtSearchByBarcode FROM sqlSearchByBarcode;
PREPARE stmtSearchByName FROM sqlSearchByName;

# EXECUTE: returns 3x resultset!!!
EXECUTE stmtSearchByCode USING what, limits, offset;
EXECUTE stmtSearchByBarcode USING what, limits, offset;
EXECUTE stmtSearchByName USING what, limits, offset;

# ... some unimportant code
```

Approach 2 - stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Search (
    IN what VARCHAR(255)
    , IN offset INT
    , IN limits INT
)
BLOCK1: BEGIN

# ... some unimportant code

# BUILD SELECTs for UNION (building SQL string)
SELECT GenerateSql(1,'c',1) INTO sqlSearchByCode;
SELECT GenerateSql(2,'b',1) INTO sqlSearchByBarcode;
SELECT GenerateSql(3,'n',1) INTO sqlSearchByName;
SELECT GenerateSql(0,' ',1) INTO sqlSearchUnion;

# PREPARE SQL
PREPARE stmtSearch FROM CONCAT(
    '(', sqlSearchByCode, ')'
    , ' UNION '
    '(',  sqlSearchByBarcode, ')'
    , ' UNION '
    '(', sqlSearchByName, ')'
    , sqlSearchUnion
);

# EXECUTE: return single resultset with one extra column "FLAG", containing 'c','b' or 'n' character tó be able to identify, where result came from (which SELECT used)!!!
EXECUTE stmtSearch USING what, limits, offset;

# ... some unimportant code
```

Comment: I would go for approach 2 since it's nearly working. Why don't you map this extra flag as a private property called productType for instance? Can you post an bit more code (entities, stored procedure)?

Comment: Thank you @b126 I added some code. Yes, this finalization is what I need to solve now. Is it possible to do it without adding flag into entity? Flag will be used just in this case, I don't need it anywhere else in app. I need help with this final steps: my idea is to receive hydrated Entities, but also access some underline associative array and get flag from here, if is possible.

Comment: Then, you could use the Native SQL feature provided by Doctrine and get an array result that you can browse the way you want. https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/reference/native-sql.html